# Juint actual and expected the same but test fails

Tags: java, junit4

I am trying to learn Junit4 and do tests for some of my code. Basically, I am reversing the string and keeps the special symbols in place. During the testing, I found this fail that I can't understand. 
My unit test fails although the actual value and expected are the same. 
Thank you in advance!

**Error:**

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
>   Expected :d1cba hgf!e
>   Actual   :d1cba hgf!e

**Code**

```
public final class AnagramsMaker {
    public static String reverseWord(String stringToReverse) {
        char[] stringToChar = stringToReverse.toCharArray();
        int arrayStart = 0;
        int arrayEnd = stringToChar.length - 1;

        while (arrayStart < arrayEnd) {
            if (Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayStart]) && Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayEnd])) {
                char temp = stringToChar[arrayStart];
                stringToChar[arrayStart] = stringToChar[arrayEnd];
                stringToChar[arrayEnd] = temp;

                arrayStart++;
                arrayEnd--;
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayStart]) && !Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayEnd])) {
                arrayEnd--;
            }
            else if (!Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayStart]) && Character.isLetter(stringToChar[arrayEnd])) {
                arrayStart++;
            }
            else {
                arrayStart++;
                arrayEnd--;
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(stringToChar);
    }

    public static String createAnagram(String inputString) {
        String anagram = "";
        String [] arr = inputString.split(" ");

        for (String s : arr) {
            anagram += reverseWord(s) + " ";
        }
        return anagram;
        } 
   }
```

**Junit:**

```
 @Test
    public void createAnagram() {
        assertEquals("d1cba hgf!e", AnagramsMaker.createAnagram("a1bcd efg!h"));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried reproducing it and got this: `expected: <d1cba hgf!e> but was: <d1cba hgf!e >`. Notice the extra space in the end.

There is a bug in `createAnagram` method. You are adding extra space after every string but for the last iteration, extra space is getting appended in the end that's causing this issue.

As fix, trim the value before returning as shown below

```
public static String createAnagram(String inputString) {
        String anagram = "";
        String [] arr = inputString.split(" ");

        for (String s : arr) {
            anagram += reverseWord(s) + " ";
        }
        return anagram.trim();
    }
```

If you are comfortable with java8 & streams, better approach would be to use `Collectors.joining` method as shown below

```
public static String createAnagram(String inputString) {
        String[] arr = inputString.split(" ");
        return Stream.of(arr)
                .map(AnagramsMaker::reverseWord)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }
```